# Store data in lucene

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene.net

I try to store users in lucene, but some of the users is not stored.
User like "k-test.com" is not stored. Why? I never get any error message or something. Other users like "test" is stored. Do i need to encode the name or something?
This is what i do:

```
private static void ResetIndex(IEnumerable<UserInfo> users)
{
    var CloudAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Blob.ConnectionString);
    var RamDIR = new RAMDirectory();
    var DIR = new AzureDirectory(CloudAccount, FolderName, RamDIR);

    IndexWriter Writer = null;
    var Analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion);

    while (Writer == null)
    {
        try
        {
            Writer = new IndexWriter(DIR, Analyzer, !IndexReader.IndexExists(DIR), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
            Writer.DeleteAll();
            Writer.Commit();
        }
        catch (LockObtainFailedException)
        {
            DIR.ClearLock("write.lock");
        }
    }

    foreach (var Pr in users)
    {
        Writer.AddDocument(GetUserInfoDoc(Pr));
    }

    Writer.Optimize();
    Writer.Dispose();
}

private static Document GetUserInfoDoc(UserInfo ui)
{
    var Doc = new Document();

    Doc.Add(new Field("UserName", ui.UserName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
    Doc.Add(new Field("FirstName", ui.FirstName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
    Doc.Add(new Field("LastName", ui.LastName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
    Doc.Add(new Field("UserNr", ui.UserNr.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));

    return Doc;
}
```

Comment: Don't analyze the field if you don't want the `StandardAnalyzer` to mangle it, or use a different analyzer for this field.

Comment: ok, so what should i do? I want to store users like "k-test.com" and then search for it. The problem is that user like "k-test.com" is not stored.